# Ignored attempt to bind route (/Nindex) to unkown controller :: usercontroller.hi

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to bind a route to my usercontroller's action hi, it renders the view.

This is in my `routes.js`

```
 'get /Nindex': {
   controller: 'UserController.hi'
 },
```

and this is in my `UserController.js` under `/api/controllers`

```
module.exports = {
    hi: function (req, res) {
        res.view('/Nindex');
    }

};
```

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title on my command prompt after running `sails lift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining two methods of declaring the route into one. Use either of:

`'get /Nindex': 'UserController.hi',`

or

`'get /Nindex': {
   controller: 'UserController',
   action : 'hi'
 },`